# Ошибка onclick - Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick + AJAX PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, html5

Пробовал по разному, и скрипты в head, и вниз документа, и проверял на кеширование (на всякий случай, а вдруг оно не показывает новые изменения), и прямой `<script>` и всё равно не работает. Помогите разобраться!!!

**PHP**

```
<?php
    echo '<button id="'.$posts->id.'" onclick="deleteFunction(item)">Удалить пост</button>';
?>
<?php require 'script.php'; ?>
```

**script.php**

```
<script src="../js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/post-delete.js"></script>
```

**post-delete.js**

```
function deleteFunction(item) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/post_delete',
        data: {post_id: item.id},
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(){
        }
    });
};
```

$posts->id - это из орм redbean php (не обращайте внимания)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо надо вместо

```
onclick="deleteFunction(item)"
```

написать

```
onclick="deleteFunction(this)"
```

Comment: Я сейчас повешусь!!! А всё из-за священного ctrl+c - ctrl+v.... Спасибо большое, я бы не заметил.